# LaTeX unintended padding and rendering in HTML

Tags: html, latex, padding

The following LaTeX

```
\(
\newcommand{bvec}[1]{\overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{#1}}}
\newcommand{uvec}[1] {\widehat{\boldsymbol{#1}}} 
\newcommand{vec}[1]{\overrightarrow{#1}} 
\)
```

inserts a padding on my HTML page.

When written in the 'head' tag space, or right under 'body':

[image: this results]

Header without the padding:

[image: without the padding]

Same story when inserted inside a paragraph, padding wherever placed. Further, I can see the code briefly (~.3 sec) when initially loading up the page:

[image: the code]

How do I rid of the padding and startup rendering?

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the problem is with the Latex code, most HTML tags tend to have padding and/or margins appended to them. The solution is to simply get rid of them using CSS. You can use [inline CSS style](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/html-inline-styles) to customize the paragraph tag.
Here is an MVCE:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>

    <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">Paragraph WITHOUT padding and margin</p>
    <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">Paragraph WITHOUT padding and margin</p>
    <p>Normal paragraph tag with padding and margin</p>
    <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">Paragraph WITHOUT padding and margin</p>
    <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">Paragraph WITHOUT padding and margin</p>
    <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">--------</p>
    <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">\(
        \newcommand{bvec}[1]{\overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{#1}}}
        \newcommand{uvec}[1] {\widehat{\boldsymbol{#1}}}
        \newcommand{vec}[1]{\overrightarrow{#1}}
        \)</p>
    <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">\(
        \newcommand{bvec}[1]{\overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{#1}}}
        \newcommand{uvec}[1] {\widehat{\boldsymbol{#1}}}
        \newcommand{vec}[1]{\overrightarrow{#1}}
        \)</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT!**

Since you using latex commands to output actual latex results (complex mathematical notations)... You should use [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/). I do recommend creating your own HTML file and run it yourself because [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com) tend to not support external files... To create an html file, please have a look at the following [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=naVmNPTxwfI). Now, I have completed the initialization of MathJax so that you would be able to start Latex coding instantly (you could use TexMaker or TexStudio and paste Latex code into your html file. Note that it tends to be limited when it comes to complex drawing like using Tikz or pgfplots (if you want such complex diagrams, you would need to render them as images and then put then in your HTML file as, of course, images.
Here is the updated code ;)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <title>Latex Example</title>
 <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
 MathJax.Hub.Config({
  tex2jax: {
  inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
  processEscapes: true
  }
 });
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
 </script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">Paragraph WITHOUT padding and margin</p>
  <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">\(
   \newcommand{bvec}[1]{\overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{#1}}}
   \newcommand{uvec}[1] {\widehat{\boldsymbol{#1}}}
   \newcommand{vec}[1]{\overrightarrow{#1}}
   \)
   $\bvec{Worked!}$ This one NO margins nor padding</p>
  <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">Paragraph WITHOUT padding and margin</p>
  <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">Paragraph WITHOUT padding and margin</p>
  <p>\(
   \newcommand{bvec}[1]{\overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{#1}}}
   \newcommand{uvec}[1] {\widehat{\boldsymbol{#1}}}
   \newcommand{vec}[1]{\overrightarrow{#1}}
   \)
   $\bvec{Worked!}$ This one HAS margins and padding</p>
  <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">Paragraph WITHOUT padding and margin</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Output!**

[image: Output]

**EDIT 2!**

You basically want to have text in, let's say, a `<p>...</p>` tag that would be invisible to the user. What you can do is to customize your `<p>` tag to the following: `<p style="display: none;">...<\p>`. Inside that `<p>` tag, the text will not be visible because the display is set to `none`. Here is the final result:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <title>Latex Example</title>
 <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
 MathJax.Hub.Config({
  tex2jax: {
  inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
  processEscapes: true
  }
 });
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
 </script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">Paragraph without padding nor margins</p>
  <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">Paragraph without padding nor margins</p>
  <p>Paragraph tag that is not customize and has marigns, padding and display value is display : block (i.e. visible to user).</p>
  <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">Paragraph without padding nor margins</p>
  <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">Paragraph without padding nor margins.</p>
  <!--
  Here is the text that is not visible to the user. This is because of "display: none;"
  -->
  <p style="display: none;">\(
   \newcommand{bvec}[1]{\overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{#1}}}
   \newcommand{uvec}[1] {\widehat{\boldsymbol{#1}}}
   \newcommand{vec}[1]{\overrightarrow{#1}}
   \)
   $\bvec{Worked!}$ This one NO margins nor padding
   Here is a tag that us useful but not visible to user
  </p>
  <!--
  Now, everything is visible from now on.
  -->
  <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">Paragraph without padding nor margins</p>
  <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">Paragraph without padding nor margins</p>
  <p>Paragraph tag that is not customize and has marigns, padding and display: block (i.e. visible to user).</p>
  <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">Paragraph without padding nor margins</p>
  <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">Paragraph without padding nor margins</p>
  <p>$\bvec{Worked!}$ This one HAS is an uncustomized tag (regular)</p>
  <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">Paragraph without padding nor margins</p>
  <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">Paragraph without padding nor margins</p>
  <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">$\bvec{Worked!!!!}$ This one is visible with no padding nor margins</p>
  <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">Paragraph without padding nor margins</p>
  <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">Paragraph without padding nor margins</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work, I'm afraid - the inserted space persists: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FU8XHDQU0CO5

Comment: I see, are you trying to produce the latex commands or the write actual/literal latex code? and what operating system are you using?

Comment: Both; I define the new commands to facilitate vector writing: http://puu.sh/BdjOw/341cc21901.png I use Windows 7 Pro

Comment: Delete '$\bvec{Worked!}$ This one NO margins nor padding', and render the rest. It appears <p></p> has an innate space which gets inserted in absence of intended text. The problem persists.

Comment: I found a 'workaround' from your code - can simply insert the code before any equations, and no space's inserted. If you find a means to rid of the space directly (i.e. <p></p> on its own no longer inserts space), do share. The matter's resolved - thank you for your assistance.

Comment: I just added a new edit, I am sure it is what you want :)